# Orange rectangle around links in WebView

Tags: android

I have a web view that is loaded with an HTML that contains links.
when I switch to another activity (say to another tab in a tab
activity) and then switching back to it, the link is surrounded with
an orange rectangle. also happens in the GoogleAdView which really
makes it impossible to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the link in the WebView has the focus. Maybe you could avoid it by letting another view request the focus (`anotherView.requestFocus();`) in onResume() or onStart().

Comment: Thanks! that helped a lot. I also needed to set this anotherView to be focusableInTouchMode(true) - which got me read all about touch mode in android. great help, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Try this to prevent webview from drawing a focus rectangle when it is first focused
        webView.getSettings().setNeedInitialFocus(false);

Comment: This really help me remove first focused rect on my WebView

Answer (score 6):

Try webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false) - it worked for me. Also, read [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html) link if you want to understand what drove me to this solution.

***You should take into account though that this solution will make all text input boxes in your webpage unavailable...***

Found another solution, but it requires access to the html itself. You need to set the following css property: -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); This will not cause the problem with the input boxes.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem and using -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); worked perfectly. Thanks!